# Movie about a startup during the dotcom

Tags: identify-this-movie, documentary

I can't seem to remmember or find the name of the movie or the company that was in the movie.

The movie was about a mobile game developer (developing on old Nokia phones) company that was based in Sweden (I believe). It was in the time before the dotcom bubble. I believe the companies name started with "a", but I'm not sure.

It was a documentary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMDB has this one, which I have not seen, but sounds very close: [Riot On!](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0427783/combined).

Here's the synopsis straight from IMDB:

> Sex, lies and mobile games
>
> The year is 2000 and investors are going crazy about a new mobile phone company called Riot Entertainment. Many high profile companies, like Nokia, invest millions on this unknown firm. Two years later, when all the money has been spent and the company is bankrupt, the fun is over. What happened?

Comment: BTW - I recently watched Startup.com, which is also about a dot-com bomb - govWorks.com. It was very interesting.

Comment: Riot Entertainment were from Finland (home of Nokia) not Sweden, but this sounds like the right one and the timing matches.